# C prog integration of JSON as wrap around to display fetched SQL table on webserver

Tags: html, c, json, sqlite

I have a problem that drives me crazy. I want to integrate JSON in the following code to use JSON as a kind of wrapper around the sqlite statements. This should be for the purpose to display just the entire sql table on a webserver page embedded in HTML. To connect to the database and fetch the table I have used sqlite3 and the given functions like sqlite3_open()/sqlite3_close() and so on. I know that sqlite3 has functions to handle JSON as well like json_array()/json_insert() etc. I think this should be a good possible solution to reach my goal. I played around with those functions a bit, but nothing has worked yet. Means there was absolutely no result. Maybe anyone knows how to put the sqlite3 commands/requests in JSON objects to display in a further step those table entries on a simple HTML page. I have to say I`m a absolutely beginer in this section, but read and tried a lot to get into it. But didnt catch it yet.

Hope you could help me. Would be very thankful for every hint to get it work.

C code:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;            
    int rc = 0;
    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db",&db);

    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf("Database could not be opened %s \n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    else
    {
        printf("Database sucessful opened");
    }

    char *sql_stmt = "SELECT * FROM students";

    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql_stmt, -1, &stmt, 0);
        
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf("\nUnable to fetch data");
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("student records\n");

    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1), 
        sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2));
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those won’t help you output JSON. Get a library that does it, use it to format output

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Which library would be advisable?

Comment: I appreciate this: https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON

Comment: @C-3PO, you make many references to JSON but it is not clear if you have a clear idea on what JSON is and you specify no library you are using to compose JSON format (JSON is a text format)  JSON indeed, has no relationship with HTML format, and so, it is a bit messy to produce HTML output that includes JSON formatted output.  There are libraries to output HTML format, as well as JSON formatted text, based on the structure (this is what your program needs to build) of your data.  But you don't show how you are producing JSON format in your code, so I cannot write an answer.

Comment: ... indeed, you can produce a perfectly valid JSON formatted page that has no HTML code at all, there's a MIME type for that (`application/json`) and this allows you to format JSON without having to frame it with HTML code.